# What should be used between Rx and .Net for event composition in such scenarios?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

As I am learning the Rx (Reactive extensions), I want to know the different between given 2 peice of code:

**Code 1**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Logs", "*.*");
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


            var source = Observable.FromEvent<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(handler =>
                {
                    FileSystemEventHandler fsHandler = (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            handler(e);
                        };
                    return fsHandler;
                },

                fsHandler => watcher.Created += fsHandler,

                fsHandler => watcher.Created -= fsHandler
                    );

            source.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name + "is created"));

            Console.Read();
}
```

**Code 2**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Logs", "*.*");
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            watcher.Created += watcher_Created;

            Console.Read();
        }


        static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name.ToString());
        }
```

What is the different between above 2 peice of code as it produce the same result?

Even I gone through the core part and found that both the code line execute on saparate thread, then what is the difference between these and why I use Rx in such scenarios??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, there are two potential benefits to using Rx (emphasis on **potential**):

- A convenient way to "unwire" the event handler: calling `Dispose` on the subscription (the thing returned by the `Subscribe` call) will have the same effect as `watcher.Created -= handler`
- A way to *compose* events coming from this source with other `IObservable` (and `IEnumerable`, for that matter) sources. For example, if your use case is "I need to know when a file is created, then written to three times, etc, etc", you can create multiple `IObservable` "watchers" from the various events exposed on the `FileSystemWatcher`, then create a query that will fire only when the correct conditions occur

in pseudo-LINQ:

```
var createEvents = <get created event handler>;
var changeEvents = <get changed event handler>;
var createThenChangeThenChangeThenChange = 
    from create in createEvents
    where create.Name == "some file I care about"
    from firstChange in changeEvents
    from secondChange in changeEvents
    from thirdChange in changeEvents
    select new { create, firstChange, secondChange, thirdChange};
```

Comment: Agreed that Rx is overkill in the OP example. It starts to become useful when composing more complex operations as you point out. It is also useful if you want to use DI to pass the event/observable around to other consumers.

Comment: @JimWooley Yeah, Rx really becomes useful once you start chaining things together...for simple one-off eventing, I usually just stick to "vanilla" methods.

Comment: true. For comparison, I have a post merging three FileSystemWatcher handlers to create a real-time MRU implementation at [ThinqLinq](http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/Reactive-Framework-Subscribing-to-Events.aspx)